# Do I need a DI BOX when sending signal from a mix console to another device?

Tags: mixer, recorder-mixer

I'll be sending a signal from mix console's AUX output to another device to record it. Do I need to put a DIBOX inbetween these two devices, or not?

The AUX output is a standard 6.3 jack connector, NOT an XLR connector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A low level signal (i.e. microphone) needs to be balanced because it will pick up too much noise over long runs.

A high level signal (line) is can survive a reasonable length unbalanced because the noise it picks up is generally not going to be noticeable.

So if your recording device was a fair distance away, you may want to use a balanced line to avoid too much noise.  If it's fairly close, you can use an unbalanced line.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you use a DI box depends on the signal, not the purpose the signal is being sent. A DI box converts from line-level to microphone level. If the recording device accepts line-level, you do not need a DI box. You may need a cable adapter, however.

Line-level is often provided unbalanced on a 6.5" jack. It is usually strong enough and not travelling far enough that that is more than acceptable. Mic-level is often provided balanced on an XLR. However, in both cases, it is possible for the signal to be provided or accepted on the opposite type of socket. Line-level on an XLR is usually so it can be balanced, which is good for long runs.

That said, going from unbalanced to balanced can be tricky with the possibility of ground loops. One way to solve that is to use an isolating transformer, which can look like a DI box, but technically isn't. A DI box will also pad the signal down, whilst an isolating transformer will do a 1:1 conversion.